# Problem with Usb Wireless Adapter (by SignalKing)

Tags: wireless, drivers, usb, adapter, wifi-hardware-switch

I have bought a USB Wireless Adapter made by SignalKing because I broke my laptop's hardware switch of the embedded adapter.
Despite the fact that I can use it on Windows without having any issue, while using Ubuntu (14.10) I get this message:

> Wi-Fi Network (Ralink 802.11 nWlan) Wi-Fi is disabled by hardware
>   switch

But there's no hardware switch on SignalKing.
The green light showing the adapter is working, is on.

Here are some of the commands I used and the output:

```
sudo rfkill unblock all
```

But nothing happened

```
lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net
```

> 02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
>
> RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136]
>
> (rev 02)    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device [1179:ff1e]
>
> Kernel driver in use: r8169 03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel
>
> Corporation WiFi Link 5100 [8086:4232]    Subsystem: Intel Corporation
>
> WiFi Link 5100 AGN [8086:1201]    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi

```
lsusb
```

> Bus 002 Device 003: ID 148f:3070 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT2870/RT3070 Wireless Adapter Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux
>
> Foundation 2.0 root hub Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux
>
> Foundation 1.1 root hub Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux
>
> Foundation 1.1 root hub Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux
>
> Foundation 1.1 root hub Bus 005 Device 002: ID 1a2c:0040 China
>
> Resource Semico Co., Ltd  Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux
>
> Foundation 1.1 root hub Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f2:b008 Chicony
>
> Electronics Co., Ltd USB 2.0 Camera Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002
>
> Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux
>
> Foundation 1.1 root hub Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux
>
> Foundation 1.1 root hub

```
sudo lshw -c network
```

> *-network
>
> ```
>    description: Ethernet interface
>
>    product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
>
>    vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
>
>    physical id: 0
>
>    bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
>
>    logical name: eth0
>
>    version: 02
>
>    serial: 00:1e:33:55:fc:92
>
>    size: 10Mbit/s
>
>    capacity: 100Mbit/s
>
>    width: 64 bits
>
>    clock: 33MHz
>
>    capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
>
>    configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half latency=0 link=no multicast=yes
> ```
>
> port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
>
> ```
>    resources: irq:44 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:d0010000-d0010fff memory:d0000000-d000ffff   *-network DISABLED
>
>    description: Wireless interface
>
>    product: WiFi Link 5100
>
>    vendor: Intel Corporation
>
>    physical id: 0
>
>    bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
>
>    logical name: wlan0
>
>    version: 00
>
>    serial: 00:16:ea:a7:23:94
>
>    width: 64 bits
>
>    clock: 33MHz
>
>    capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
>
>    configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.16.0-24-generic firmware=8.83.5.1 build 33692
> ```
>
> latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
>
> ```
>    resources: irq:46 memory:d4200000-d4201fff   *-network DISABLED
>
>    description: Wireless interface
>
>    physical id: 2
>
>    bus info: usb@2:2
>
>    logical name: wlan1
>
>    serial: 00:25:22:48:a8:8e
>
>    capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
>
>    configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800usb driverversion=3.16.0-24-generic firmware=N/A link=no multicast=yes
> ```
>
> wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn

```
sudo rfkill list all
```

> 0: phy0: Wireless LAN
>
> Soft blocked: no
>   Hard blocked: yes
>
> 1: phy1: Wireless LAN
>   Soft blocked: no
>   Hard blocked: no

lsmod

> Module                  Size  Used by bnep                   19543  2  rfcomm                 69509  0  bluetooth             446190  10
>
> bnep,rfcomm 6lowpan_iphc           18702  1 bluetooth hid_generic
>
> 12559  0  coretemp               13441  0  kvm_intel
>
> 143553  0  snd_seq_midi           13564  0  kvm
>
> 459843  1 kvm_intel snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
>
> snd_rawmidi            30876  1 snd_seq_midi joydev
>
> 17344  0  uvcvideo               81065  0  videobuf2_vmalloc
>
> 13216  1 uvcvideo videobuf2_memops       13362  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
>
> radeon               1416372  3  serio_raw              13434  0
>
> videobuf2_core         59104  1 uvcvideo snd_seq                67224
>
> 2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi v4l2_common            15682  1
>
> videobuf2_core snd_hda_codec_realtek    76887  1
>
> snd_hda_codec_generic    68914  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek parport_pc
>
> 32741  0  snd_hda_codec_hdmi     47547  2  videodev
>
> 149725  3 uvcvideo,v4l2_common,videobuf2_core ppdev
>
> 17671  0  r852                   18075  0  sm_common
>
> 16860  1 r852 media                  21963  2 uvcvideo,videodev lp
>
> 17759  0  parport                42299  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc usbhid
>
> 52574  0  snd_hda_intel          30379  5  snd_hda_controller
>
> 35152  1 snd_hda_intel hid                   110426  2
>
> hid_generic,usbhid nand                   68630  2 r852,sm_common
>
> snd_hda_codec         139675  5
>
> snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller nand_ecc               13312  1 nand snd_hwdep              17698  1
>
> snd_hda_codec nand_bch               13227  1 nand bch
>
> 17397  1 nand_bch nand_ids               12723  1 nand snd_pcm
>
> 104102  4
>
> snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller arc4
>
> 12608  4  mtd                    59628  2 nand,sm_common ttm
>
> 89406  1 radeon drm_kms_helper         61627  1 radeon r592
>
> 18040  0  iwldvm                236430  0  memstick
>
> 16966  1 r592 lpc_ich                21093  0  toshiba_acpi
>
> 28320  0  drm                   310919  6 ttm,drm_kms_helper,radeon
>
> iwlwifi               182909  1 iwldvm i2c_algo_bit           13406  1
>
> radeon sparse_keymap          13948  1 toshiba_acpi wmi
>
> 19193  1 toshiba_acpi toshiba_bluetooth      12867  0  snd_seq_device
>
> 14497  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi snd_timer              29513
>
> 2 snd_pcm,snd_seq snd                    87611  21
>
> snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
>   rt2800usb              27139  0  rt2x00usb              20742  1
>
> rt2800usb rt2800lib              93180  1 rt2800usb rt2x00lib
>
> 55170  3 rt2x00usb,rt2800lib,rt2800usb soundcore              15052  2
>
> snd,snd_hda_codec shpchp                 37040  0  video
>
> 20128  0  mac80211              660592  4
>
> rt2x00lib,rt2x00usb,rt2800lib,iwldvm mac_hid                13227  0
>
> cfg80211              510218  4 iwlwifi,mac80211,rt2x00lib,iwldvm
>
> crc_ccitt              12707  1 rt2800lib psmouse               106548
>
> 0  firewire_ohci          44323  0  ahci                   34062  4
>
> libahci                32424  1 ahci sdhci_pci              23261  0
>
> sdhci                  43448  1 sdhci_pci firewire_core          68671
>
> 1 firewire_ohci r8169                  71471  0  crc_itu_t
>
> 12707  1 firewire_core mii                    13934  1 r8169

```
dmesg | grep rt2
```

> [    6.208167] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00_set_rt: Info - RT chipset 3070, rev 0201 detected [    6.301516] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00_set_rf:
>
> Info - RF chipset 0005 detected [    6.375882] usbcore: registered new
>
> interface driver rt2800usb

Answer (score 0):

It may seems naive but in my thinkpad t430 when I deactivate the wireless using the hardware switch it also blocks the usb adapter (and I got this same message), to make it work I just to keep the switch on.